# How do I extract a stacktrace from threads in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, multithreading, try-catch

I'm very confused with handling errors on runnables passed to a threadpool.

I am doing everything by the book (literally, I'm adhering to Goetz' "Concurrency in Practice") and I'm not capturing any errors that Eclipse is showing me, and I'm getting weird NoClassDefFoundErrors even though my buildpath looks fine.

[image: Weird NoClassDefFoundError even though my buildpath is fine]

I tried killing my local repo and recloning it to get a fresh project build, but still getting the error. And none of my try-catches or System.out.println's are working either. Is there any way Eclipse can give me a better view of the error? Or a way to actually get the error handler's to work?

```
//ThreadPool and runnable that is failing, even with error captures
MyPriorityThreadPool.execute(new RunWithPriority(priority) {
                        Throwable thrown = null;
                        @Override
                        public void run() { 
                                try {
                                    batch.buildData();
                                } catch (Exception e) {
                                    thrown = e;
                                }
                                finally {
                                    if (thrown != null) { 
                                        thrown.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, but the reason you're not catching the `NoClassDefFoundError` in your code is that you're catching `Exception` instead of `Throwable` or `Error`. `Exception` is more specific than `Error` and *not* what `NoClassDefFoundError` inherits from, so `NoClassDefFoundError` isn't caught by your `catch` expression.

Comment: I think that worked... it printed the stack trace after I changed the type to Exception. As for the NoClassDefFoundError, it turned out a singleton failed to initialize properly and broke some stuff. Thanks!